# terraform CLI slow on windows

Tags: windows, terraform

terraform CLI is very slow on windows for me.

I have created batch script below to time it:

```
echo %time%
terraform
echo %time%
```

where the output is following:

[image]

I don't think simply calling terraform without any arguments should take 32 seconds. Does anyone here have the same issues? I have run terraform init without a backend, so a remote backend timing out shouldn't be the problem.

Pretty much a duplicate of [Terraform slow to start on Windows. Known issue or just me?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46552808/terraform-slow-to-start-on-windows-known-issue-or-just-me), but that question has been open for 4 years. I'm hoping that problems like this are more wellknown now.

Comment: Well, instead of asking the same question again, you could have placed a [bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) on the original question in order to attract more attention…

Comment: the question isn't clear, is it not slow on the same pc running different OS or inside a vm or a container?

Comment: @aschipfl Sorry, I did not know that would make it more noticeable, I will do it now.

Comment: @Mohamed I have not tried on a different OS, but according to the old question, it is not this slow on mac or linux.

Comment: @MyrionSC2 there is just too many variables to figure out whats the underling issue is, it could be the network, the disk, something  specific with your system .... etc

Comment: @Mohamed That is fair enough. I just downloaded the cli to my home pc and no problem there. I will try to debug what the difference is on my work PC later and update this question then.